# How would I incorporate a tie counter in my tic tac toe code? I would like to put it at the end of my program

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

This is all for tic tac toe.I have a method that checks for the winner and it could go in there. I think I need to search for numbers on the game board and if any remain then it is not a tie and if there some remain it is a tie.

```
    public class TicTacToe { //Beginning of TicTacToe
    static String[][] board = new String[3][3];

public static void main (String [] args) { // Main routine
String move; //User input
String marker = "O"; //The character/marker starts at O and switches to X
// asigning variables
boolean computer = false; 
boolean done = false;
boolean playAgain = true;
int wins[] = {0,0,0};//1st. p1 wins, 2nd. p2/comp wins, 3rd. ties

System.out.println("Do you want to play against computer (y/n)? Typing no will give you a 2 player board.");
computer = TextIO.getlnBoolean(); //Option and input that player 1 gets to choose if they want to play against computer or player2

do { //Beginning of play again loop
  fillArrays();// fills the arry with values
  printBoard(); // prints the board
  do { //Beginning of loop that runs the board
    marker = switchMarker(marker); // turns o into x  
    do { // error check loop
      move = getUserMove(marker, computer); 
    } while (!isMoveValid(move));
    insertMove(marker, move);
    printBoard();
    done = checkForWinner();
  } while(!done);
  printWinner(marker,wins);
  playAgain = getPlayAgain(); //Sets the variable play again to the method getPlayAgain, which asks the user if he/she wants to play again
} while(playAgain); //Loops while play again is true
    } //End of main routine

 public static void fillArrays(){ //fills the game board 
int number =1;
for(int a=0; a<3; a++) {
  for (int b=0; b<3; b++) {
    board[a][b]= String.valueOf(number++);
  }
}


 }

  public static boolean getPlayAgain(){ //meathod to play again
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
    String playAgain = TextIO.getln();
    if(playAgain.equals("y")){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static boolean isMoveValid(String mov) { //error checks numbers greater than 9 and less than 0

    int numMove = Integer.parseInt(mov);

    if (numMove < 1 || numMove > 9) { 
      System.out.println("Sorry but your move is not valid! Please re enter:");
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public static String switchMarker(String marker){ // replaces O with X
    if(marker.equals("X")){ 
      return "O";
    }
    else{
      return "X";
    }
  }

  public static String getComputerMove(){ //determins where the computer decides to play
    boolean found = false;
    String randString;
    do{
      int rand =(int)(Math.random()*9)+1;
      randString = Integer.toString(rand);
      for(int a=0;a<3; a++){
        for(int b=0;b<3; b++){
          if(randString.equals(board[a][b])){
            found = true;
            // try and code for 
          }
        }
      }
    }while(!found);
    return randString;
  }
  public static String getUserMove(String marker, boolean computer){ //chooses computer or player2
    if(marker.equals("X")){
      System.out.println("Player 1 please enter your move");
    }
    else if(computer){
      return getComputerMove();
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Player 2 please enter your move");
    }
    return TextIO.getln();
  }

  public static void insertMove(String move, String spot){ // places character on the board
    for(int a=0;a<3; a++){
      for(int b=0;b<3; b++){
        if(spot.equals(board[a][b])){
          board[a][b] = move;
        }
      }
    }
  }  



  public static void printBoard(){ //prints the board

    for(int a=0;a<3; a++){
      for (int b = 0; b<3; b++){
        System.out.print(board[a][b] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    } 
    System.out.println();


  }

  public static boolean checkForWinner(){ // checks all possible win combos


    //combo 1 - horizontal line
    for(int a=0;a<3; a++){ //horizontal checks
      if((board[a][0].equals(board[a][1]))&&(board[a][1].equals(board[a][2]))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    //combo 2 - vertical lines
    for(int a=0;a<3; a++){ //vertical checks
      if((board[0][a].equals(board[1][a]))&&(board[1][a].equals(board[2][a]))){
        return true;
      }
    }
    //combo 3 - diagonal lines
    if((board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]))&&(board[1][1].equals(board[2][2]))||(board[0][2].equals(board[1][1]))&&(board[1][1].equals(board[2][0]))){
      return true;
    }

    //If the above haven't returned true, then we either haven't won yet.. or it's a tie.


    //Cycle through looking for any number in the board. If there isn't one, the board is full, and because we know
    //there isn't a winning move on the board.. it must be full! So, return true.



    return false; //Return false. We don't have a winner yet.
  }

  public static void printWinner(String marker,int wins[]){ // counts wins, ties and losses
    if(marker.equals("X")){
      System.out.println("Player 1 you win!");
      wins[0]++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Player 2 you win!");
      wins[1]++;
    }
   // if (
    System.out.println("Player 1 has " + wins[0] + " wins and Player 2 has " + wins[1] + " wins and there are " + wins[2] + " ties.");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: checkForWinner() is where i would like it to check for a tie

Answer (score 0):

Absolute simplest is to maintain a count of `number_of_moves_performed`.  When that reaches `9`, and there is no winner, you've got a tie.  No need to search all board positions for an unmarked square.

Comment: I have created a counter and what will happen at 9 slots full. I don't know where to place the counter though?

Comment: Since your entire class uses static methods, to share the counter between two or more static methods, you'll need to make your counter static as well.  `static int number_of_moves_performed;`  You could add that below your `static String[][] board = ...` line.

Comment: You'll need to reset the counter at the start of each game (eg, in `fillArrays()`), and increment only for a valid move (eg, in `insertMove()`).